# Create a zip if the folder creation_date has todays date using powershell

Tags: powershell

I have written the following script and it never returns the zip file created although the folder creation_date equals todays date

```
# Define the path to your folder and backup folder
$sourceFolder = "C:\Deployment"
$backup
Folder = "C:\Backup"
$source = Get-Item $sourceFolder
$today = Get-Date

if (-not (Test-Path $backupFolder)) {
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $backupFolder
    Write-Host "Backup Folder created successfully."
} else {
    Write-Host "Backup Folder already exists."
}

# Check if the folder creation has todays date
if ($sourceFolder.CreationTime.Date -eq $today.Date) {
    Write-Host "Deployment Folder was created today."
    # Compress the folder into a zip file
    $zipFileName = "$backupFolder\backup_$today.zip"
    Add-Type -A 'System.IO.Compression.FileSystem'
    [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::CreateFromDirectory("$sourceFolder", $zipFileName)
    Write-Host "Folder zipped successfully. Backup created at $zipFileName"
} else {
    Write-Host "Deployment Folder was not created today."
}
```

Please let me know if the above script has any errors

Comment: To get the current date in `YYYYMMDD` format to a string, you can use `(Get-Date).ToString("yyyyMMdd")`. I have not tested your code so just wanted to drop a comment on that specific part. Don't forget to append your variables with `$` and to ensure all are defined before running logic that uses them.

Answer (score 0):

It has a bunch of trivial errors.

First of all, you are trying to get the `CreationDate` property of a string: `$sourceFolder.CreationTime.Date`. `$source`, which is of `DirectoryInfo` type, should be used instead.

Then you got stuff like:

```
$backup
Folder = "C:\Backup"
```

which is invalid syntax, I assume this is a copy paste error. You should ensure that whenever you're asking questions, the minimal reproducible example makes sense and can be executed.

Comment: Please do not write in Answer section. The stuff which you made should be in comments section.
Anyhow, I figured the script and it works fine for me

Comment: If you think this literal answer needs to be in comments then your question is simply not worth existing on this website... You should then reconsider posting such questions instead of teaching people what goes where while having 0 answers yourself. I don't disagree with that line of thought and I'll recheck if you pressed the delete button.